Prove $\underset{x\in X}{\inf}f(x)$ is continuous
Consider an arbitrary set $X$ and $\mathscr{B}(X;\mathbb{R})$ the set of the bounded functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Define the real functions $I$, $S$: $\mathscr{B}(X;\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We put $I(f)=\underset{x\in X}{\mathrm{inf}}f(x)$ and $S(f)=\underset{x\in X}{\mathrm{sup}}f(x)$. Prove that $I$ and $S$ are continuous. Note: for distance between functions, the book uses the metric $d(f,g)=\underset{x\in X}{\sup}|f(x)-g(x)|$.
For the continuity of $S$, I used the hint in here and it worked fine:
Given $\varepsilon>0$, let $|S(f)-S(g)|<\varepsilon$.
$f(x)\leq|f(x)-g(x)|+g(x)\Rightarrow S(f)\leq d(f,g) + S(g)$.   *
But it is also true that $g(x)\leq|f(x)-g(x)|+f(x)\Rightarrow S(g)\leq d(f,g) + S(f)$. **
From $(*)$ and $(**)$, $d(f,g)\leq|S(f)-S(g)|,\Rightarrow d(f,g) < \varepsilon$, so $S$ is continuous.
I couldn't generalize the hint to prove continuity of $I$ and I'd appreciate some help. This exercise came from the second chapter of a metric spaces book. I'm not supposed to use concepts like "compactness" or "infinite sequences" because they weren't defined yet. I can only use metric properties and the definition of continuity.

We have $I(f)=\displaystyle\inf_{x\in X}f(x)=-\sup_{x\in X}-f(x)=-S(-f)$.
The map $g:\mathscr{B}(X;\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathscr{B}(X;\mathbb{R})$ given by $g(f)=-f$ is trivially continuous, and as it is already proved that $S$ is continuous, the continuity of $I$ follows.

Thank you for the answer!
